# proj4leaflet with esri-leaflet 1.0.4

Tags: leaflet, esri-leaflet, proj4js

We need to add esri-tile layer in leaflet .At first ,we tried proj4leaflet with esri-leaflet 2.0.0 and leafelt 1.0.0. It workded fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <!-- Load Leaflet from CDN-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet/1.0.0-rc.2/leaflet.css" />
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet/1.0.0-rc.2/leaflet.js"></script>

    <!-- Load Esri Leaflet locally, after cloning this repository -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri/2.0.2/esri-leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.15/proj4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4leaflet/0.7.2/proj4leaflet.js"></script>

    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        margin:0; padding:0;  width : 100%; height : 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
     var esri = L.esri.tiledMapLayer({
  url: 'http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/ESRI_Imagery_World_2D/MapServer',
  maxZoom: 15
});


       var map = L.map('map', {
        layers: [esri],
        center: [34.82209 , 113.2982],
        zoom: 8,
        crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Our program is built on leaflet 0.7.7 only working with esri-leaflet 1.0.4. So we also tried it with leaflet 0.7.7 and esri-leafelt 1.0.4 ,but it complains *L.esri.TiledMapLayer is using a non-mercator spatial reference* .

Is it possbile to run proj4leaflet without upgrading leafelt and esri-leaflet ？

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to include the most important part of the message!

> `L.esri.TiledMapLayer` is using a non-mercator spatial reference. Support may be available through Proj4Leaflet

this isn't a complaint, its a reminder that you should use Proj4Leaflet if you are interested in supporting a basemap in a custom projection.

live demo - http://jsbin.com/cemaqiv/edit?html,output

Leaflet 1.x has introduced *substantial* improvements in custom projection support. if you insist on loading a non-mercator basemap like Plate Carree i'd highly recommend that you upgrade.

further reading - why 4326 is usually the wrong projection:
http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2009/02/06/Why-EPSG4326-is-usually-the-wrong-e2809cprojectione2809d

Comment: Even when I run the demo code by my firefox , it will also remind me of this message that I should use proj4leaflet. And there is something wrong with center position of the map. I guess the only solution is to upgrade leaflet and other libraries.